# To find the tangent of a given curve.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

The given curve is
$$y^2(a+x)=x^2(3a-x).$$

It is given in my book that when we equate the minimum order term of equation to zero,
$$a(y^2-3x^2)=0,$$
we get $y=\sqrt{3}x$, $y=-\sqrt{3}x$, which is tangent at origin.

I don't know how do we choose minimum order term of equation?

Comment: I have never heard of the phrase "minimum order term" of a general equation.  A quick search with Google and Bing didn't turn anything up either.  Unless I'm missing something obvious, as other people here may also not be clear on what you mean, perhaps you can provide a definition, or at least clarify, what this means based on what it says in your book.  Also, it's not clear to me, but I think you are saying that this will provide the tangent at the origin.  If not, then also please clarify that as well.

Comment: I read this term in some local book. Niether I am clear about this. Maybe they mean, minimum degree term. I am not sure.

Comment: Mathsaddict, my guess would also be minimum degree.  However, if this is what was meant, note this would not necessarily be unique.  For example, which one, if any, of $x^2$, $xy$ and $y^2$ would be considered to be the minimum degree term?

Comment: Actually, I guess that if the equation can be written as a polynomial in $x$, then perhaps the "minimum degree term" would be the one with the lowest power of $x$.  If so, then, how would any constant term be treated as, if it's not already $0$, then it can't be $0$, unless it means to use the lowest non-$0$ power of $x$?

Comment: If the equation is written as a polynomial in $x$, we get  $x^{3}-3ax^{2}+y^{2}x+ay^{2}=0$.       Here minimum degree term is $y^{2}x$.

Comment: Mathsaddict, I forgot that the term without any $x$ could, and most likely usually does, involve $y$, as indicated by the equation you wrote.  However, in your case I believe it should be $ay^2$ instead of $y^2x$.

Comment: @John Omielan I think the writer just compared the degrees of all terms, then he collected all terms with lowest degree and equated them to zero. Here, in this curve the minimum degree of  the terms is $2$ so he put all the terms with degree two at one side of equation and equated this side to $0$.